# How to get td text value of nested table by XPath

Tags: xpath, htmlunit

I have this table inside another table inside another table and so on. And then I want to get the text value of the td element with a specific class.

```
<tr>
  <td width="5%"></td>
  <td class="wintxt">The XML ....<br/><br/>Number: xyz</td>
</tr>
```

I need to get the text content "The XML ....Number: xyz"

I tried using:

```
List<?> submissionString = resultOfsubmissionPage.getByXPath("//tr[@class=\"wintxt\"]/td/text()");
```

...and many other variations but I always get a zero element List. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: May be class mistake try this :- `//tr/td[@class='wintxt']/text()`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I get two elements in my List. Is those two elements the 2 tds in the tr ?

Comment: but as i seeing only one `td` has class attribute which is specify with the xpath...

Comment: The two elements i get are: 0)The XML...
1)Number: xyz ,  so thats great. Thanks

Comment: yeah it returns two element with desire text..you welcome..glad to help you..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is mistakes with your provided `xpath` you are searching `text()` in that row means `tr` which has class attribute but as your provided HTML only one `td` has class attribute. So try as below :-

```
List<?> submissionString = resultOfsubmissionPage.getByXPath("//tr/td[@class='wintxt']/text()");
```

Hope it helps..:)